# Django - Use the slug from the view in the template

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I use a (class-based) view's slug in the template? I want to use it again in other urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the slug from your views with:

```
{{ view.kwargs.slug }}
```

If you want to use in another url:

```
{% url 'my_url_name' view.kwargs.slug %}
```